# Java wrap text to polygon

Tags: java, text, graphics, word-wrap

I am using Java Graphics2D to draw basic and complex polygons which will have text of varying lengths and fonts in it. What I'm trying to achieve is that the text drawn is perfectly wrapped and clipped to fit within the polygon.

The code I have so far is this:

```
int[] xp = { x + width /2, x + width -1, x };
int[] yp = { y, y + height - 1, y + height - 1 };
g.setColor(fill.color1);
g.fillPolygon(xp, yp, xp.length);
g.setColor(border.color);
g.setStroke(new BasicStroke((float) (border.width * zoom), BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));
g.drawPolygon(xp, yp, xp.length);

// Later on in the method..
g.drawString(text, textx, texty);
```

This draws the shape and text fine but the text is just one long line. I want it to fit neatly into the polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution has worked well for me. I used alhugone's advice and decided to compute where the text should go inside a Shape. This is what I did:

```
public static void wrapTextToPolygon(Graphics2D g, String text, Font font, Color color, java.awt.Shape shape, int x, int y, int border)
{
    FontMetrics m = g.getFontMetrics(font);
    java.awt.Shape poly = shape;
    int num = 0;
    String[] words = new String[1];
    if(text.contains(" "))
    {
        words = text.split(" ");
    }
    else words[0] = text;
    int yi = m.getHeight() + border;
    num = 0;
    while(num != words.length)
    {
        String word = words[num];
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((poly.getBounds().width / 2) - (m.stringWidth(word) / 2) + x - border - 1, y + yi, m.stringWidth(word) + (border * 2) + 2, m.getHeight());
        while(!poly.contains(rect))
        {
            yi += m.getHeight();
            rect.y = y + yi;
            if(yi >= poly.getBounds().height) break;
        }
        int i = 1;
        while(true)
        {
            if(words.length < num + i + 1)
            {
                num += i - 1;
                break;
            }
            rect.width += m.stringWidth(words[num + i]) + (border * 2);
            rect.x -= m.stringWidth(words[num + i]) / 2 - border;
            if(poly.contains(rect))
            {
                word += " " + words[num + i];
            }
            else
            {
                num += i - 1;
                break;
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if(yi < poly.getBounds().height)
        {
            g.drawString(word, (poly.getBounds().width / 2) - (m.stringWidth(word) / 2) + x, y + yi);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        yi += m.getHeight();
        num += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to scale font size or/and break text.
to measure text width, you can use:

```
// get metrics from the graphics
FontMetrics m= g.getFontMetrics(font);
int strWidth = metrics.stringWidth("MyTexxt");
```

Comment: That would work fine for a rectangle but what about a triangle or a star? Also reducing font size isn't an option. I would rather have some of the text cut off.

Comment: I think you have to compute the area of text inside them, and if text is too long cut off it on your own. For every type(triangle, star..) it will be probably different algorithm.

Comment: Well that really sucks. Surely there must be some inbuilt function to do this? I know that the Polygon class has a function to test if a point is within it's boundaries, maybe this could be used somehow?

Comment: Look for some library that already implements what you need. I'm sure there are few. Maybe [ObjectDraw](http://www.zahniser.net/~russell/computer/index.php?title=ObjectDraw%20Library)